# Replacing images with jquery - js.erb - Rails

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, ajax

I have a ajax call right now that changes the state of an object. When the click action happens I also want it to change the background image of that particular object in the UI. I'm trying to find the best way of doing this. I've tried the replaceWith method but it was printing text and not image. If anyone know of an easy way to do this that would be great, Thanks.

### View

```
<tbody>
  <tr class="<%= snitch.classes %>">
    <td>
        <%= link_to "<span id='snitch_#{snitch.token}_icon' class='icon led'></span><span>#{snitch.name}</span>".html_safe, snitch_path(snitch), class: "name"%>
    </td>
    <td class="interval"><span class="vspace"><%= snitch.interval %></span></td>
    <td class="last-checked">
      <span class="vspace">
        <% if snitch.source.checked_in_healthy_at %>
          <span data-tooltip="Checked in healthy at UTC(<%= snitch.source.checked_in_healthy_at.to_i %>) || LOCAL(<%= snitch.source.checked_in_healthy_at.to_i %>)">
            Last seen <strong><%= snitch.checked_in_healthy_at(title: nil) %></strong>
          </span>
        <% else %>
          <strong><%= snitch.checked_in_healthy_at %></strong>
        <% end %>
      </span>
    </td>
    <td class="snitch-controls" data-icons="<%= snitch.pauseable? ? "5" : "4" %>">
      <%= render 'menu', snitch: snitch %>
      <nav class="snitch-states" >
        <% if snitch.pauseable? %>
          <%= link_to 'Pause', pause_snitch_path(snitch, remote: true), class: 'icon icon-pause pause',
            data: { tooltip: "Pause" },
            rel: "modal:open" %>
        <% end %>

        <%= link_to 'Delete', delete_snitch_path(snitch), rel: 'modal:open',
          data: { tooltip: "Delete" },
          class: 'icon icon-delete delete', title: "Delete #{snitch.name}" %>
        </nav>
    </td>
  </tr>
</tbody>
```

### JS

```
 $('#snitch_<%= @snitch.token %>_icon').append("")
```

This is obvi incomplete attempt at what I'm trying to do but something like this? maybe?

Comment: Do you want to always switch to a specific bg image or ...?

Comment: no Just once the state has changed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like all links share a common class `name`. So, it is better to select your links by that CSS class, rather than each by its ID. Also, an easy way of doing it would be to simply add additional class on click and change the background image in your CSS file.

**Something like this:**

```
$('.name').on('click', function(e){
  $(this).addClass('clicked');
});
```

```css
.name {
  background-image: url('first.png');
}

.name.clicked {
  background-image: url('changed-image.png');  
}
```